# Rails routes: json endpoint naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes

I have an endpoint that renders json:

```
def controller_method
   render json: json_response
end
```

However, I am curious about the naming convention of the route. The following naming leads to `ActionController::UnknownFormat Controller#controller_method is missing a template for this request format and variant.`:

```
get '/controller/controller_method.json', to: 'controller#controller_method'
```

However, I successfully get the json when the route is named:

```
get '/controller/controller_method_data', to: 'controller#controller_method'
```

Am I not allowed to put `.json` in the url routes? Any way that I can allow `.json` be the name of the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way to respond to different formats - just use [ActionController::MimeResponds](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

```
get '/controller/controller_method', to: 'controller#controller_method'
```

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  def controller_method
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { hello: 'world' } }
      format.html # renders the view implicitly
      format.txt { render plain: 'Hello world'}
    end
  end
end
```